# Find the vertical and horizontal asymptotes of this function

Tags: limits, functions

$$F(x)= \frac{\sqrt{9x^2-5x}}{x+3}$$

Ok, so the horizontal lines $y=3$ and $y=-3$ are horizontal asymptotes because $\displaystyle\lim_{x \rightarrow \pm\infty}F(x) = \pm3$. But, what about vertical asymptotes? 
Is there a way to simplify this function so I can show things more clearly?

Comment: Our function blows up as $x$ approaches $-3$ from the right, and becomes very large negative as $x$ approaches $0$ from the left. Simplification is not needed to see this.